# Jenkinsfile Groovy Pipeline Text Parameter Whitespace

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

currently I wish to added a multliline text parmeter to a groovy pipeline. If the text parameter is not left column alighed (no space before paramter), then whitespace is injected into the text parameter list.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Here is the code

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

node {

    def startTime = new Date()
    println "Build start time : " + startTime

    // Load system parameters
    def projectProperties = [
    [$class: 'EnvInjectJobProperty', info: [loadFilesFromMaster: false, secureGroovyScript: [classpath: [], sandbox: false, script: '']], keepBuildVariables: true, keepJenkinsSystemVariables: true, on: true]
    ]

    // Set project parameters  
    projectProperties.add(parameters([
        string(name: 'infraRepo', description: 'Repo Name', defaultValue: 'my-infrastructure' ),
        string(name: 'infraBranch', description: 'Repo Branch', defaultValue: 'develop' ),
        string(name: 'projectName', description: 'Project name', defaultValue: 'think-more' ),
        // Text field not left side aligned now whitespace will be injected
        text(name: 'ecrRepoAndVersion', description: 'ECR Docker name and version number',
        defaultValue:'''address=3.0.1
        address-details=3.0.1
        auth=3.2.1'''),
        choice(name: 'clusterName', description: 'Ecs cluster name', choices: '---Select---\nblue-ci\ngreen-ci', defaultValue: '---Select---'),
]))

    properties(projectProperties)

    // Print system variables
    sh 'env | sort'
}
```

And here is an image of how the Jenkins Job UI looks after this pipeline is executed. Note the whitespace in the ecrRepoAndVersion field.

[image: Jenkins UI View]

Comment: Instead of doing a literal string with `'''`, have you tried using an interpolated string with `"""` and specifying newlines with `\n`? That should work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [strip indent in groovy multiline strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19882849/strip-indent-in-groovy-multiline-strings)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you - that worked perfectly.

```
text(name: 'ecrRepoAndVersion', description: 'ECR Docker name and 
version number',defaultValue:"""address=3.0.7-RC\n
address-details=3.0.3-RC\nauth=3.2.3-RC""")
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting aside the need for this logic, I would add a bit more readability and ease of maintenance by joining a list of items, instead of verbatim specification:

```java
def ecrRepoAndVersionItemsDefault = [
    "address=3.0.7-RC",
    "address-details=3.0.3-RC",
    "auth=3.2.3-RC",
]
...
// then construct an ArrayList
def jobParams = []
jobParams << ...
...
jobParams << text(
    name: 'ecrRepoAndVersion',
    description: 'ECR Docker name and version number',      
    defaultValue: ecrRepoAndVersionItemsDefault.join('\n')
)
// then add the properties
...
projectProperties.add(parameters(jobParams))
...
properties(projectProperties)
... 
// etc.
```