# Groovy string output on multiple lines without space

Tags: string, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have following string with a lot of characters as an example with Groovy:

```
def test = '''aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
              bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
              cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc'''    
println test
```

**Current output**:

```
'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
               bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
               ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
```

**Expected output**:

How could I modify this instead to print like this so that there would not be those spaces on the left on lines 2 and 3?

```
 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
 bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
 ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
```

I found about line continuation character \ but it seemed that it did not affect output in expected way.

I have also tried at least like this:

```
def test = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa' +
            'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb' +
            'cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc'    

println test
```

Output with that was:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbcccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
```

My actual use case would be longer descriptions written to Jenkinsfile for couple of parameters and faced this originally there on Jenkins-pipeline but reproduced with this short Groovy-example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few options:

1. Just don't line your string up in the editor:

```
def test = '''aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc'''
```

2. Use stripMargin and the `|` character:

```
def test = '''aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
             |bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
             |ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc'''.stripMargin()
```

3. Use stripIndent and an escape char:

```
def test = '''\
             aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
             bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
             ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc'''.stripIndent()
```

I almost exclusively use 2 as it's the happy place between readable and obvious

Comment: Thanks! Also seems that expected result was achieved when a single `'` mark was used around the string on each line, a newline character `\n` added to lines 1 + 2 and also `+` to lines 1 and 2. Options 2 and 3 look very good, just not sure if `stripMarging()` or `stripIndent()` work on Jenkinfile but I can test tomorrow when I have access to the actual environment.

Comment: Oh yeah, you can do it oldschool too with `'...\n' + '...'` or `"...\n" + "..."`... it's easier to miss a `\n` and spend hours debugging though 

Comment: using java standard [trim](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_trim.htm) should be ok, also a good explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19882917/6382363) as well